# How to obtain link presentation text in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I've built a parser for a Wikipedia page in Python which is as follows:

```
    ...
    data = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'mw-content-ltr'});
        for div in data:
            links = div.findAll('a', href=True, title=True)
            for l in links:
                print l
```

Which finds all of the links within a given div area; producing:

```
...
<a href="/wiki/Lumber" title="Lumber">lumber</a>
<a href="/wiki/Arecaceae" title="Arecaceae">palms</a>
<a href="/wiki/Cyatheales" title="Cyatheales">tree ferns</a>
<a href="/wiki/Banana" title="Banana">bananas</a>
<a href="/wiki/Bamboo" title="Bamboo">bamboo</a>
```

But how do I obtain the word that presents the link, so the "bananas" or the "bamboo"? I would get the title, but I need to know which words are linked, rather than where they're linked to.
I've seen a question which allows me to get the next sibling, but that's the text after the link, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the .contents parameter, I think this is what you want.
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents

Comment: That works, but do you know why python returns things like this:
[u'Metasequoia'], with the [u...] annotations?

Comment: Cheers :) I just Googled it anyway.